# Delete Negative Acknowledgement character in word

Tags: vba, ms-word, ascii

I'm working on a vba macro in word that trims given characters from the end of a range.  Whenever I have it try to delete the *Negative Acknowledgement Character* I get the error *Cannot edit Range*.  The range has the size of exactly 1 and contains only the character with ASCII value 21.

What is the purpose of this character in a MS Word doc, why can't I delete it, and how could I delete it?  I need to delete the character because whenever I insert text before or after it my inserted text becomes "**Error!**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to select the range and then use `Selection.Delete` like so:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range(i, i + 1) 
Debug.Print Asc(rng.text) ' 21
rng.Select
Selection.Delete
```

Why does `Selection.Delete` work and not `Range.Delete`? IDK.  I expect Selection be nothing more than the alias to the selected range but its not so.  Selection is it's own class with it's own doc page and everything.